# Simple Injector and routeattribute webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, routes, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

I have a WebApi 2 Application and I'm using simple injector and all is working ok.

But today I tried to use the [RoutePrefix] and [Route] attributes to resolve my routes on a particular controller and it seems that simple injector is not able to create an instance of my controller.

i'm getting this error

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'NewController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor. Type
>   'Public.API.Controllers.NewController' does not have a default
>   constructor

Stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) 
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) 
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) 
at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) 
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) 
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

my controller looks like this

```cs
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/New")]
public class NewController : ApiController
{
    private IUserService userService;
    public NewController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(ApiRegisterUserRequestModel model) {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "reponse");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ForgotPasswordSendEmail")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPasswordSendEmail(
        [FromBody] ApiForgotPasswordRequestModel model)
    {
        var response = "cool";
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
}
```

If I make a request to the `Register` action I get a response, but if I make a request to the `ForgotPasswordSendEmail` action then I get the error I mentioned above.

The simple injector configuration I have is the Basic setup mentioned here

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html

**UPDATE**
I'm using `OWIN` and `JWT` token authentication, and I have a `global.asax` and a `startup` file in my project and both were configured to use webapi.

These were my `Startup` class and `Application_Start`

```cs
//startup class
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer.Initialize();
        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);

        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}

//Application_Start
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    SimpleInjector.Configure();
    SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer.Initialize();
}
```

I removed all of the api configuration from the `startup` and left if like this

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
    }
}
```

and it started to work.

now, why wasn't it working using the `[Route]` attribute and without it all was fine?  it's a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to reproduce this issue, but with no success. You typically get the "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor" error in case the registered `IDependencyResolver.GetService` returns null and the requested type does not have a default constructor.

If you, as you said, follow [Simple Injector's configuration guidance](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html), the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` will not return `null`, but will either return a valid controller instance -or- will throw an expressive exception. The default guidance states that you at least do the following:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

container.Verify();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

If you use this code, it's very unlikely that you get this "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor" error. Especially in the situation where the controller can be resolved when called using one action, while it fails to initialize during another.

So please check the following:

1. You are using the code as shown above.
2. Are you sure that api/New/Register call actually goes through the `NewController`. You can set a break point in its constructor and the `Register` method.
3. The `NewController` can actually be resolved correctly when manually calling `container.GetInstance<NewController>()`.